# Is there a way to disable resolving symlinks for OSX 'open' utility?

Tags: macos, symbolic-link, open

Suppose I have file called `a.txt` and another file `b.txt` which is a symlink pointing to  `a.txt`. I also have my own developed application which is set as a default application for `.txt` files. Now when I type

```
$ open b.txt
```

in Terminal, it looks like the `open` utility has automatically resolved the symlink because my application has received `a.txt` as a parameter at launch.

Is there a way to disable resolving symlinks for OSX `open` utility ? I checked the manual page of `open` but there is nothing about symlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround:

```
$ open -a /Applications/MyApp.app --args <path_to_file>
```

This forces `open` to pass the argument unchanged. But there's a catch - if you pass relative path as an argument, then the path is relative to /Applications, not your current directory, which is kind of annoying. But it's the best solution I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find a.txt -type f -exec open {} \;
```

-> this open your a.txt file.

```
$ find b.txt -type f -exec open {} \;
```

-> no file is open.

Comment: From the question, it appears that the questioner doesn't want the files to **not open**.  Xe wants the files to open **with the original name**, rather than the name taken from the contents of the symbolic link.

Comment: Yes, exactly as JdeBP says. But I'm not sure if that's possible, so some sort of workaround is also fine. This one is a bit complicated though.